# how to add the hexadecimal strings list to get the total hexadecimal value

Tags: python, list, type-conversion, hex

I want to add all  hexadecimal values in the list and to get hexa decimal value (as 0x44).

I tried to convert the list values  to int then added them and then converted back to hex but value was 0x32.

please suggest me way to add the string hexadecimal list to get the hex value.

```
lst = ['0x0', '0x0', '0x1', '0x1', '0x1', '0x1', '0x1', '0xf', '0xf', '0xf']

total =  sum(lst)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./prog.py", line 3, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert the hex strings into hex values with int() first.

```
>>> lst = ['0x0', '0x0', '0x1', '0x1', '0x1', '0x1', '0x1', '0xf', '0xf', '0xf']
>>> sum([int(_, 16) for _ in lst])
50
>>> hex(sum([int(_, 16) for _ in lst]))
'0x32'
```

Comment: Good. But I find this syntax more readable - `sum(int(x, 16) for x in lst)`  And you don't have to create a `list` then `sum` them, just `sum(generator exp.)` would be more efficient.